# Windows FTP failed to work

Tags: windows, ftp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Command-line FTP function does not work](https://superuser.com/questions/215775/command-line-ftp-function-does-not-work)

I am trying to copy file to a remote ftp account, but failed.

The same FTP file upload work in filezilla but not working in windows FTP command line.

The settings:

```
port: 21
transfer mode: active
type: plain ftp
```

I go to command line then

```
ftp
lcd "C:\testfolder"
open 1.2.3.4 21
user dummyuser
password dummypassword
cd "httpdocs/log"
binary
prompt n
put "abc.txt" (hangs at put)
```

When it hang, the message show is: 150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for abc.txt

abc.txt is successfully created at remote ftp, but the file content is 0 byte.

It keep on hang there.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, found the fixes.

[Command-line FTP function does not work](https://superuser.com/questions/215775/command-line-ftp-function-does-not-work)

comment by Pants, saying add ftp.exe into windows firewall exception list do works.

Answer (score 0):

Using Windows 7 I found that "File Transfer Program" was already in my "Inbound Rules" list in Windows Firewall (once for TCP and once for UDP), however it still wasn't working.

To make it work I needed to edit those rules and change "Profiles" (in Advanced tab) from just private to public, private and domain.