# File upload batch

Tags: windows-7, command-line, ftp, batch

I am trying to write a batch file that will Upload and update a specific set of file on my desktop to an FTP account, so I wrote this batch:

```
@ftp -i -s:"%~f0"&GOTO:EOF
open DomainName.com
USERNAME
PASSWORD
binary
cd  httpdocs/myfiles
lcd F:\Test\Folder1
mput *.bmp
close
quit
```

by testing the above batch, everything work good until it reaches the line:

```
mput *.bmp
```

once this line is reached, connection freeze and the only way to resume after that is by restarting the router

So can someone please help me by telling me what exactly I am doing wrong here?

Update:
1. FTP server I am trying to upload to is Linux based (CentOS) 
2. I am using a Windows XP - SP1 machine to execute this batch file
3. I've tried clicking CTRL+C to terminate the batch but still, even though the batch is terminated the connection remain freezed until I restart the router

Update 2:
Here is the exact output of the commands I enter:

```
ftp
open domainname.com
220 ProFTPD 1.3.4a Server <ProFTPD> [IP ADDRESS of our server]
User <domainname.com:<none>>: USERNAME
331 Password required for USERNAME
Password: PASSWORD
230 User USERNAME logged in
ftp> binary
200 Type set to I
ftp> cd httpdocs/myfiles
250 CWD command successful
ftp> lcd F:\Test\Folder1
Local directory now F:\Test\Folder1
ftp> mkdir MyTest1
257 "/httpdocs/myfiles/MyTest1" - Directory successfully created
ftp> put test.bmp
```

Freeze connection and router

Comment: Which router you have?

Comment: Have you tried anything to debug this?  Try adding `dir` after the `cd`.  Try replacing the `mput *.bmp` with `put foo.bmp`.  And — am I missing something?  Are you FTPing _into_ a router, or into some ordinary computer?  It might help if you told us what your FTP server is.  (And have you tried hitting `Ctrl+C` when your connection freezes?)  (Also, can you sniff the network traffic?)

Comment: @Scott I've edited my question and added replies to all your questions at the footer of my question
Regarding sniff of network traffic, I am sorry but I am not that experienced to know how to sniff network traffic :)

Comment: @Scott I've copied and pasted the output of the commands at the end of my question

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/326911/windows-ftp-failed-to-work

Comment: Can you get FTP file transfer to work between these two machines (in either direction) by any means?  Can you do a `dir` after the `cd`?

Comment: Yes I can easily connect between the two machines using FTP programs (ex. FileZilla)

Comment: @sgmoore I followed the instructions in the link but it still doesn't work :(

Comment: What instructions did you follow. In particular did you try typing QUOTE PASV after you login?

Comment: @sgmoore instructions in this link http://superuser.com/questions/326911/windows-ftp-failed-to-work

No I didn't notice the QUOTE PASV, but I've just tried it now and same results :( connection freeze :(

Answer (score 0):

After

```
lcd F:\Test\Folder1
```

try

```
lcd F:\Test\Folder1
mkdir MyTest
```

Check that MyTest was created properly.  I suspect that your router can't find the directory but isn't throwing an error.  When the transfer begins is when it is caught.

I don't see anything wrong with

```
mput *.bmp
```

Comment: I've just tried mkdir it worked just fine, but mput didn't work :( 

I've also copied and pasted the commands output log in my original question above.

Answer (score 0):

OK, the problem isn’t specifically in the `MPUT` command.  Unless you are able to get some FTPs to work, I’m going to go out on a limb and guess that your problem is the same as in the previous questions on this subject — something in the network path between the two machines (including the router and the hosts themselves) is blocking TCP port 20. 
(FTP uses two port numbers: 21 for control information and 20 for data.  Clearly port 21 is getting through.)  If FTP was working until recently, see whether something changed: did a sysadmin tighten some firewall rules?

Comment: No actually I don't have any firewall installed on the client machine which i use to connect to the FTP server, and even Firewall is disabled