# Windows FTP client getting error as Connection closed by remote host

Tags: ftp, file-transfer, ubuntu-14.04, windows-server-2012-r2, vsftpd

I am using Windows server 2012 R2 and have wndows default FTP client applications working. However, when I use command-line FTP, I can get connected, log in (after entering user name and password), but when I try to use the command put to transfer files it always gets disconnected. But all the other command working fine such as `OPEN LCD CD Bin` when I try to use put to transfer files the response i am getting is:

> Connection closed by remote host.

FTP server is ubuntu 14.04 LTS and using vsftpd as the file transfer service.

Below is the full list of commands that am trying to use.

```
ftp> open 202.124.175.197
Connected to 202.124.175.197.
220 (vsFTPd 3.0.2)
User (202.124.175.197:(none)): ftpuser
331 Please specify the password.
Password:
230 Login successful.
ftp> lcd \\waterplus\dfs\WS02\Logs\WhvIntApiGW1.waterplus.co.uk\WSO2APIM_GWWKR
Local directory now \\waterplus\dfs\WS02\Logs\WhvIntApiGW1.waterplus.co.uk\WSO2A
PIM_GWWKR.
ftp> cd /home/ftpuser/Move/WhvDmzApiGw1.newco.co.uk
250 Directory successfully changed.
ftp> put audit.log.2018-01-11
Connection closed by remote host.
ftp>
```

Seeking for help to sort this issue out.

Comment: *"have wndows default FTP client applications working"* - What do you mean by that? + Do you get the error immediately after using `put`? Or after some time?

Comment: Particularly see my answer:  https://superuser.com/a/884975/213663

Comment: @MartinPrikryl yes, this error is coming after some time, executing 'put'

Comment: Do my links help?

Comment: Hi @MartinPrikryl It says some limitation on windows FTP client. But lot of sources shows how windows FTP client works. I am bit confused now. Please advice me on this.

Comment: Confused about what? `ftp.exe` can indeed work, but in the active mode only. For that, you have to open the firewall. My answers covers that https://superuser.com/a/884975/213663