# Batch w/ ftp transfer

Tags: batch-file, ftp

I tried getting a file off of my ftp server with a batch file. Here is what happens:

```
ftp> open files.000webhost.com 21
Connected to us-east-1.route-1000.000webhost.awex.io.
220 ProFTPD Server (000webhost.com) [::ffff:145.14.145.124]
500 OPTS UTF8 not understood
User (us-east-1.route-1000.000webhost.awex.io:(none)):
331 User ***** OK. Password required

230-Your bandwidth usage is restricted
230 OK. Current restricted directory is /
ftp> lcd C:\Users\micah\Desktop\MiniventureLauncher\Game
Local directory now C:\Users\micah\Desktop\MiniventureLauncher\Game.
ftp> cd public_html
250 OK. Current directory is /public_html
ftp> binary
200 TYPE is now 8-bit binary
ftp> recv miniventure.jar
200 PORT command successful
150-Connecting to port 50186
150 13336.1 kbytes to download
```

Then it just stops. Here's the code in my batch file:

```
@Echo Off
Set _FTPServerName=files.000webhost.com 21
Set _UserName=*****
Set _Password=*****
Set _LocalFolder=C:\Users\micah\Desktop\MiniventureLauncher\Game
Set _RemoteFolder=public_html
Set _Filename=miniventure.jar
Set _ScriptFile=transfer
:: Create script
 >"%_ScriptFile%" Echo open %_FTPServerName%
>>"%_ScriptFile%" Echo %_UserName%
>>"%_ScriptFile%" Echo %_Password%
>>"%_ScriptFile%" Echo lcd %_LocalFolder%
>>"%_ScriptFile%" Echo cd %_RemoteFolder%
>>"%_ScriptFile%" Echo binary
>>"%_ScriptFile%" Echo recv %_Filename%
>>"%_ScriptFile%" Echo quit
:: Run script
ftp -s:"%_ScriptFile%"
Del "%_ScriptFile%"
```

It connects to the server, but it won't download the file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Command-line FTP function does not work](https://superuser.com/questions/215775/command-line-ftp-function-does-not-work)

Comment: It does say "230-Your bandwidth usage is restricted". Is the file large? Maybe you are limited to a certain limit per session? Does this work in a client like filezilla? "150-Connecting to port 50186" is this port open? Try running ftp with `-d` `ftp -d -s:"%_ScriptFile%"` for more debug information.

Comment: I hope the username and password in the file aren't you actual username/password. If they are, please change your password asap (at your provider, hiding it here won't help).

Comment: Als, what happens if you run the commands manually?, Try adding 'hash' before transferring the file.

Comment: djsmiley2k, I tried running it from the command prompt and the same results came up

Comment: Sorry, but there's no point trying any commands. The problem is the firewall. As shown in the answers to the question I've linked in my first comment! So please do read it, instead of wasting time, waiting here for any miraculous answer.

Answer (score 0):

As @martin-prikryl suggests in the comments, this is almost certainly a Windows firewall issue.

While Windows `ftp` can connect to a remote host without special permission, to download files, incoming remote transfers need to be explicitly allowed through the Windows firewall.

**Allowing Incoming Transfers**

If there are no Windows firewall rules for Windows `ftp`, when you run it with the `recv` command, you should be prompted to add Incoming rules to the Windows firewall automatically. The box marked `Private networks [...]` should be checked by default. Press the *Allow access* button to add the appropriate rules to your Windows firewall.

*ex. Allow downloads via Windows ftp.exe*

[image: Add Windows Firewall Rule - Screenshot]

You shouldn't need to check the box marked `Public networks [...]` unless you intend to use Windows `ftp` away from home. You'll need to be an administrator to adjust firewall rules.

Note that, unfortunately, this will not allow the current download to continue. You will need to abort the current operation (usually with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>) and try again.

**No Firewall Pop-up Is Displayed**

If the transfer hangs and no firewall rules pop-up is displayed, this most likely means that there are already existing rules in the Windows firewall for Windows `ftp` (these are added even if you initially press *Cancel* in the dialog box above). Furthermore, it is likely these rules are set to block any incoming connections (indicated by circle icons with slashes through them).

*ex. Windows ftp.exe blocked by the Windows firewall*

[image: ftp.exe Blocked By The Windows Firewall - Screenshot]

To change this:

1. Open *Control Panel\System and Security\Windows Firewall* and click the link marked *Advanced settings* on the left hand side.
2. In the *Windows Firewall with Advanced Security* dialog (shown above), click the *Inbound Rules* link on the left and wait for the primary pane to populate. Look for the two rules marked *File Transfer Program*. You can click on the *Name* category heading to sort items alphabetically, as needed.
3. For each rule, right-click it and select *Properties*. Under the *General* tab, change the *Action* from `Block the connection` to `Allow the connection`. Press *OK* at the bottom of the dialog when finished.

   *ex. Updating Windows firewall rules for Windows ftp.exe*

   [image: Unblock Windows ftp.exe Firewall Rule - Screenshot]
4. If done correctly, the cirles-with-slashes icons should be replaced with green check marks.

   *ex. Windows firewall rules for Windows ftp.exe - green check marks*

   [image: Windows ftp.exe Firewall Rule Green Check Marks - Screenshot]

---

***Creating Your Own Rules***

*On the off chance you wish to manually add (create) these rules yourself, proceed through Steps 1 and 2, except click* New rule... *on the right-hand side after selecting* Inbound Rules.

*Make one rule for TCP connections and one rule for UDP connections (protocol options are listed under the* Protocols and Ports *tab). Make sure that* All Ports *are allowed. Adjust the* Scope *tab properties (usually set to* Any IP Address *) and the* Advanced *tab* Profiles *(ususally  just `Private`) as needed.*

*Lastly, under the* Programs and Services *tab, put e.g. `C:\windows\system32\ftp.exe` as the program path (if in doubt, you can use `where ftp` from a command prompt to display the proper path).*

---

Comment: Nice answer, but why don't you post it to the [original question](https://superuser.com/q/215775/213663), and vote for this one to be closed as duplicate?