# FTP Server file download issue

Tags: linux, unix, ftp, sftp, winscp

I am trying to download a from FTP server from Unix command prompt but getting "Connection closed by remote host" exception.

Same exception I am getting while trying from Window command prompt as well but using WinScp able to download file without any issue.

Not able get that is the issue. We want to schedule file download task using crontab .

Can anyone give me some idea to investigate the root cause.

Note - connecting FTP server using user and password

Please see below the steps that I am following. I dont know where to check FTP log while executing FTP command in window command prompt.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFuiw.png)

There might be some firewall is blocking but wondering I am able to do the same using Winscp from same system.

Comment: How are you connecting, active or passive? When exactly does the error arrive? Tried disabling security? Firewall? Read and comment in your post on [link1](https://superuser.com/questions/215775/command-line-ftp-function-does-not-work) and [link2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37539/vsftpd-fails-pam-authentication).

Comment: @ Martin Prikryl, Not able to find FTP logs in window 10 system. I have added steps that  I followed in my question section

Comment: @ harrymc, If any Firewall and Security is blocking my FTP command then same activity  can also blocked while I am performing using Winscp tool also. Is there any specific settings available in Winscp tool that I am missing from command prompt ?

Comment: Please do not post output as an image, post it as a text. `ftp` has `-d` switch to enable debugging. Both on Windows and *nix. + WinSCP default to the passive mode. Contrary to Windows `ftp`, which does not even support the passive mode. *nix `ftp` usually does support the passive mode (though it may not default to it).

Comment: @ Martin Prikry, thanks, In Window it did not work but after making passive in Linux it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost all modern FTP servers run in passive mode - your command line FTP client may default to active mode and would give you this disconnect message.

Try the following:

```
ftp> open <server>
<login with username and password>
ftp> passive
ftp> get <file>
```

You should get confirmation of passive mode after entering the passive command.

Comment: Thanks "Peleion" your suggestion worked.