# Connect my ftp server, filezilla client works well, why ftp command line fails?

Tags: vba, cmd.exe, ftp, lan, wan

I'm trying to build up Excel VBA programmatically and expect it could download some files from the server via the FTP command line. The server which I set up at my home local network(experimental period), provides FTP service to internet users. (Later I should move it to a VPS for more stable running)

**What I have done includes:**

1. Set up IIS FTP service,
2. Server PC's firewall,
3. Routers firewall and forwarding service;

**What I have tested successfully includes:**

1. LAN PC FTP command line downloads the FTP server's file;

```
...
230 User logged in.
ftp> Get "\CalData\22-12-21.txt" "C:\Downloads\CalData\22-12-21.txt"
200 PORT command successful.
125 Data connection already open; Transfer starting.
226 Transfer complete.
ftp: 1065 bytes received in 0.04Seconds 23.67Kbytes/sec.
```

2. WAN PC *Filezilla Client* login and download the FTP server's file;

**The final step fails, when I try to:**
WAN PC FTP command line downloads the FTP server's file.

```
...
230 User logged in.
ftp> Get \CalData\22-12-21.txt C:\Downloads\CalData\22-12-21.txt
501 Server cannot accept argument.
150 Opening ASCII mode data connection.     (...frozen here...)
Aborting any active data connections...     (Ctrl+C to quit)
425 Cannot open data connection.
ftp> binary                                 (Try again with Bin mode)
200 Type set to I.
ftp> Get \CalData\22-12-21.txt C:\Downloads\CalData\22-12-21.txt
150 Opening BINARY mode data connection.    (...frozen still...)
Aborting any active data connections...     (Ctrl+C to quit)
425 Cannot open data connection.
ftp> quote pasv                             (Try again with passive mode)
227 Entering Passive Mode (94,14,216,186,196,105).
ftp> Get \CalData\22-12-21.txt C:\Downloads\CalData\22-12-21.txt
150 Opening BINARY mode data connection.    (...frozen still...)
Aborting any active data connections...     (Ctrl+C to quit)
425 Cannot open data connection.
ftp> dir                                    (Try list directory)
501 Server cannot accept argument.
150 Opening ASCII mode data connection.     (...frozen still...)
Aborting any active data connections...     (Ctrl+C to quit)
425 Cannot open data connection.
ftp?> quit
```

**What I have tried to replace some parts of the above setup include:**
Use Filezilla Server to replace IIS FTP, but the result is the same.

**My question is what kind of reason could bring the failure? how should I fix it?**
Noted that, the WAN pc works well with Filezilla Client access. I suspect that I should do something with FTP commands to enable the WAN pc access the FTP server correctly.

Any advice much appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: The Windows command-line FTP client is severely limited. For example, it does not support Passive Mode, making it virtually useless.

Comment: See https://superuser.com/q/215775/213663#884975

Comment: Thank you both. Because my work has to be done in Excel VBA, I have some knowledge of building up an FTP connection in VBA, but it heavily relies on FTP command lines, or  InternetConnectA Lib "wininet.dll", they both fail to connect the FTP server.  

Do you have any suggestion on VBA to connect FTP without windows command lines, but still can programmatically control the connection and disconnect? Thanks.

Comment: If you want to ask about your VBA wininet problem, you will have share with us [mcve]. But such question would belong back to [so].

Comment: Thank you, Martin, I believe wininet.dll has a similar issue as the FTP command line, I will try 3rd party FTP like WinSCP first as a script solution, and report my test result here.

Comment: Well, wininet supports the passive mode. So while it may also fail, it won't be for *"similar"* problems. Though, I obviously want talk you out of using my WinSCP :)

Answer (score 0):

The plan of using InternetConnectA Lib "wininet.dll" eventually works through WAN PC to access the FTP server with VBA scripts. As Martin mentioned, using passive mode is the key. Thanks, Martin again.

It of course works in the LAN network. Below are the codes I used, FYI.

```
Private Const INTERNET_SERVICE_FTP   As Long = &H1
Private Const INTERNET_FLAG_PASSIVE  As Long = &H8000000
Private Const INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD   As Long = &H80000000

Private Declare Function InternetOpenA Lib "wininet.dll" ( _
    ByVal sAgent As String, _
    ByVal lAccessType As Long, _
    ByVal sProxyName As String, _
    ByVal sProxyBypass As String, _
    ByVal lFlags As Long) As Long
 
Private Declare Function InternetConnectA Lib "wininet.dll" ( _
    ByVal hInternetSession As Long, _
    ByVal sServerName As String, _
    ByVal nServerPort As Long, _
    ByVal sUsername As String, _
    ByVal sPassword As String, _
    ByVal lService As Long, _
    ByVal lFlags As Long, _
    ByVal lcontext As Long) As Long
 
Private Declare Function FtpGetFileA Lib "wininet.dll" ( _
    ByVal hConnect As Long, _
    ByVal lpszRemoteFile As String, _
    ByVal lpszNewFile As String, _
    ByVal fFailIfExists As Long, _
    ByVal dwFlagsAndAttributes As Long, _
    ByVal dwFlags As Long, _
    ByVal dwContext As Long) As Long
    
Private Declare Function InternetCloseHandle Lib "wininet" ( _
    ByVal hInet As Long) As Long

Public Sub FtpDownload(ByVal strRemoteFile As String, ByVal strLocalFile As String, ByVal strHost As String, ByVal lngPort As Long, ByVal strUser As String, ByVal strPass As String)
'Usage: Call FtpDownload("CSMDailyAll.txt", "C:\Downloads\FXData\CSMDailyAll.txt", "myftp.com", 21, "User", "Password")

'1.Delete Target File
  Call DeleteFile(strLocalFile)
  
'2.Open Internet Shell, Check Availablility
  Dim hOpen As Long: hOpen = InternetOpenA("FTPGET", 1, vbNullString, vbNullString, 0)
  If hOpen = 0 Then MsgBox "Internet Connection Error...":  GoTo End_Sub
  
'3.Build up FTP connection with Passvie mode
  Dim hConn As Long: hConn = InternetConnectA(hOpen, strHost, lngPort, strUser, strPass, INTERNET_SERVICE_FTP, INTERNET_FLAG_PASSIVE, 0)
  If hConn = 0 Then MsgBox "FTP Connection Fails...":       GoTo Cls_Opn
  
'4.Get Target File, with no cache (always Reload)
  Dim hFGet As Long: hFGet = FtpGetFileA(hConn, strRemoteFile, strLocalFile, 1, 0, INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD, 0)
  If hFGet = 0 Then MsgBox "FTP Getting File Error...":     GoTo Cls_Con
  
'5.Check,Wait FileTransfer Complete
  Do
    If FileExists(strLocalFile) Then Exit Do Else DoEvents  'Prevents Excel from being unresponsive
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:01")             'Wait for OneSecond
  Loop
  
'6.Close Connections
Cls_Con: InternetCloseHandle hConn
Cls_Opn: InternetCloseHandle hOpen
  
End_Sub: End Sub

Public Function FileExists(ByVal FileToTest As String) As Boolean       'CheckFile Existence
  FileExists = (Dir(FileToTest) <> "")
End Function

Public Sub DeleteFile(ByVal FileToDelete As String)                     'DeleteFile
  If FileExists(FileToDelete) Then Kill FileToDelete
End Sub
```

Reference Links:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wininet/nf-wininet-internetopena
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wininet/nf-wininet-internetconnecta
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wininet/ftp-sessions
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/Wininet/nf-wininet-ftpgetfilea
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wininet/api-flags